# What are the face maps in Kan complex?

Tags: category-theory

For example, in a Kan complex, there should be three face maps from $3$-morphisms to $2$-morphisms, but a $k$-morphism only has one source $2$-morphism and one target $2$-morphism, so what's the value of the third face map?

On nlab, it is stated that
[image]
So what are the boundary $n$-morphisms of an $(n+1)$-morphism?

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental point you seem to have missed is the definition of a Kan complex: it's a kind of simplicial set. The 3-simplices are not "3-morphisms" in the sense you're thinking, with a single 2-morphism domain and 2-morphism codomain, but rather are literally 3-simplices, with four 2-simplices as faces. Such an object can be *interpreted* as an $\infty$-groupoid, but not in an immediately obvious way. For instance a 2-simplex with boundary $(f,g,h)$ may be interpreted as a 2-morphism $g\circ f\to h$. But note that there is no distinguished edge $g\circ f$ in a Kan complex!